# Cookies won't set unless I inspect element

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

So I am adding a cookie on a wordpress website in header.

```
setcookie("var", $var, time()+3600, "/", "website.com");
```

The problem is the cookie is visible and usable in php only if I inspect element -> application -> cookies (in browser).
Otherwise I keep refreshing the page and going through the website with no cookie set.
I know the cookie shouldn't be visible the first page load but even after the first load there is no cookie.

Not sure what's the problem at this point.

So I am setting the cookie on a subfolder /sub which is a wordpress file. And I am planning to use it on the index.php
There's no issue there since after I inspect it and the cookie shows up everything works as expected.

Comment: Can you share your full code and especially where you plan on reading the cookie?

Comment: I've updated the thread. That is the only line of code I use to set the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

If it shows up in your dev tools, the cookie was set - period.

You are actually just setting it, never querying it's value in your code. So how would you know if the cookie was set?

Just try `var_dump($_COOKIE)` - it should show the `var` cookie after you load the page a second time after the cookie has been set.

Comment: so, on index.php I am checking if the cookie gets set. I can refresh and surf through the cookie set pages for days, the index doesn't find the set cookie. but as soon as I inspect the dev tools it shows up and everything works perfectly.

Comment: Is there any network request / trigger / ajax going on what could cause an additional request? It's really hard to tell with the little information you provide.

Comment: I added the cookie set at the beginning of the header.php file on a default wordpress 2020 theme. I'm glad to share any kind of code that would help you help me but I don't really know what I'm doing. I assume wordpress has a bunch of other stuff going on with the cookies that could affect this maybe? Not sure.

Comment: Well, from the docs: "If output exists prior to calling this function, setcookie() will fail and return FALSE. If setcookie() successfully runs, it will return TRUE. This does not indicate whether the user accepted the cookie." - so what is your setcookie() returning?

Comment: If I try to echo $_cookie['var'] in my wordpress files it doesn't show anything, blank.